# Method with REQUIRES_NEW called from REQUIRES_NEW causes NullPointerException in TransactionalInterceptorRequiresNew

Tags: jpa, transactions, cdi

I'm having a hard time understanding what is wrong with my code...

There is a `@Singleton` EJB:

```
@Singleton
public class MailJobScheduler {

    @Inject
    private NewJobSchedulerBA newJobSchedulerBA;

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/10")
    public void doCheckForLongRunningJobs() {
        try {
            LOG.info("Checking for long running mail jobs...");
            newJobSchedulerBA.checkForLongRunningJobs(mailJobDAO);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unknown error while checking for long running mail jobs", e);
        }
    }
}
```

It just calls a method from `NewJobSchedulerBA`. This is the implementation:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public <T extends AbstractAsyncJobBE> void checkForLongRunningJobs(JobDAO<T> jobDAO) {
        JobDAO.LongRunningJobs longRunningJobs = jobDAO.findLongRunningJobs();
        longRunningJobs.getJobs().stream()
            .filter(job -> !job.wasWarningMailSent())
            .forEach(job -> {
                LOG.info("Found long running job: {}", job);
                // the update is done inside a new transaction, so if something goes wrong with updating
                // one job entity the other updates might still succeed
                jobMonitoringBA.markJobAsBeingNotified(job);
                jobMonitoringBA.sendWarningMail(job, longRunningJobs.getWarningTime());
            });
    }
```

It's inside a CDI bean and annotated with `REQUIRES_NEW`, so if anything goes wrong inside it I don't want my scheduler to expunge the timer.

This in turn calls `JobMonitoringBA.markJobAsBeingNotified(...)` (which is also a CDI bean):

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void markJobAsBeingNotified(AbstractAsyncJobBE job) {
        LOG.info("Updating job...");
        job = this.entityManager.merge(job);
        job.setWasWarningMailSent(true);
        LOG.info("Done");
    }
```

The idea here is that when a single job cannot be updated (because of, e.g., an `OptimisticLockException`, then the other jobs should still getting updated.

When I force an `OptimisticLockException`, then I get this log output:

```
[2021-07-23T12:11:10.001+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [com.bmw.swhrl.job.processor.scheduler.MailJobScheduler] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070001] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Checking for long running mail jobs...]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.002+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [com.bmw.swhrl.dao.impl.AbstractJobDAOImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070002] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Finding long running jobs...]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.002+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070002] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: connection: 2021-07-23 12:11:10.002--ServerSession(1144457050)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--client acquired: 223416353
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.003+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070003] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-07-23 12:11:10.003--UnitOfWork(60223483)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--TX binding to tx mgr, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.003+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070003] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-07-23 12:11:10.003--ClientSession(223416353)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--acquire unit of work: 60223483
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.003+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070003] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-07-23 12:11:10.003--UnitOfWork(60223483)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--begin unit of work flush
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.003+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070003] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-07-23 12:11:10.003--UnitOfWork(60223483)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--end unit of work flush
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.003+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070003] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Fine]: sql: 2021-07-23 12:11:10.003--ServerSession(1144457050)--Connection(128547665)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--SELECT ID, job_name, num_jobs_per_execution, warning_time_in_seconds FROM swhrl.job_type_configuration WHERE (job_name = ?)
    bind => [MailJobBE]
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.005+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070005] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-07-23 12:11:10.005--UnitOfWork(60223483)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--begin unit of work flush
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.005+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070005] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-07-23 12:11:10.005--UnitOfWork(60223483)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--end unit of work flush
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.005+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070005] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Fine]: sql: 2021-07-23 12:11:10.005--ServerSession(1144457050)--Connection(1207842220)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--SELECT id, bcc_recipients, content, created_by, created_date, job_failure_reason, job_result, job_status, recipients, stages, start_date, stop_date, subject, version, was_warning_mail_sent, job_id FROM swhrl.mail_job WHERE ((job_status = ?) AND (start_date < ?))
    bind => [STARTED, 2021-07-23 11:56:10.004]
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.010+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [com.bmw.swhrl.dao.impl.AbstractJobDAOImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070010] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Found 1 jobs]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.011+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [com.bmw.swhrl.job.processor.control.impl.NewJobSchedulerBAImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070011] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Found long running job: MailJobBE[ id=1 ]]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.011+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [com.bmw.swhrl.job.processor.control.impl.JobMonitoringBAImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070011] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Updating job...]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.012+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070012] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: connection: 2021-07-23 12:11:10.012--ServerSession(1144457050)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--client acquired: 2016554542
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.012+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070012] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-07-23 12:11:10.012--UnitOfWork(613966548)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--TX binding to tx mgr, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.013+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070013] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-07-23 12:11:10.013--ClientSession(2016554542)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--acquire unit of work: 613966548
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:10.017+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035070017] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Fine]: sql: 2021-07-23 12:11:10.017--ServerSession(1144457050)--Connection(1633715874)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--SELECT id, bcc_recipients, content, created_by, created_date, job_failure_reason, job_result, job_status, recipients, stages, start_date, stop_date, subject, version, was_warning_mail_sent, job_id FROM swhrl.mail_job WHERE (id = ?)
    bind => [1]
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:50.863+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [com.bmw.swhrl.job.processor.control.impl.JobMonitoringBAImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035110863] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Done]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:50.863+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035110863] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-07-23 12:11:50.863--UnitOfWork(613966548)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--TX beforeCompletion callback, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:50.864+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035110864] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-07-23 12:11:50.864--UnitOfWork(613966548)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--begin unit of work commit
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:50.880+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035110880] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-07-23 12:11:50.88--ClientSession(2016554542)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--TX beginTransaction, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:50.881+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035110881] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Fine]: sql: 2021-07-23 12:11:50.881--ClientSession(2016554542)--Connection(1452902274)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--UPDATE swhrl.mail_job SET was_warning_mail_sent = ?, version = ? WHERE ((id = ?) AND (version = ?))
    bind => [true, 4, 1, 3]
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:50.886+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035110886] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Warning]: 2021-07-23 12:11:50.884--UnitOfWork(613966548)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-5006] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.OptimisticLockException
Exception Description: The object [MailJobBE[ id=1 ]] cannot be updated because it has changed or been deleted since it was last read. 
Class> com.bmw.swhrl.entities.domain.MailJobBE Primary Key> 1
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.OptimisticLockException.objectChangedSinceLastReadWhenUpdating(OptimisticLockException.java:144)
    ...

[2021-07-23T12:11:50.887+0200] [Payara 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.jta.com.sun.enterprise.transaction] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035110887] [levelValue: 900] [[
  DTX5014: Caught exception in beforeCompletion() callback:
javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Exception [EclipseLink-5006] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.qualifier): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.OptimisticLockException
Exception Description: The object [MailJobBE[ id=1 ]] cannot be updated because it has changed or been deleted since it was last read. 
Class> com.bmw.swhrl.entities.domain.MailJobBE Primary Key> 1
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl$1.handleException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:743)
    ...

[2021-07-23T12:11:50.890+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035110890] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-07-23 12:11:50.89--UnitOfWork(613966548)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--TX afterCompletion callback, status=ROLLEDBACK
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:50.890+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035110890] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: transaction: 2021-07-23 12:11:50.89--UnitOfWork(613966548)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--release unit of work
]]

[2021-07-23T12:11:50.890+0200] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035110890] [levelValue: 800] [[
  [EL Finer]: connection: 2021-07-23 12:11:50.89--ClientSession(2016554542)--Thread(Thread[__ejb-thread-pool4,5,main])--client released
]]

[2021-07-23T12:12:16.311+0200] [Payara 4.1] [WARNING] [] [com.bmw.swhrl.job.processor.control.impl.NewJobSchedulerBAImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035136311] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Error while trying to send warning message for job: [MailJobBE, id=1, error=Managed bean with Transactional annotation and TxType of REQUIRES_NEW encountered exception during commit javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.]]]

[2021-07-23T12:12:25.409+0200] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [com.bmw.swhrl.job.processor.scheduler.MailJobScheduler] [tid: _ThreadID=116 _ThreadName=__ejb-thread-pool4] [timeMillis: 1627035145409] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Unknown error while checking for long running mail jobs
javax.transaction.TransactionalException: Managed bean with Transactional annotation and TxType of REQUIRES_NEW encountered exception during commit java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.cdi.transaction.TransactionalInterceptorRequiresNew.transactional(TransactionalInterceptorRequiresNew.java:122)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.cdi.transaction.TransactionalInterceptorRequiresNew.transactional(TransactionalInterceptorRequiresNew.java:111)
    ... 51 more
]]
```

Here I don't understand the `NullPointerException`. Following the log outputs for the transaction, one can see that a new transaction (A) is created when entering `checkForLongRunningJobs()` and another one (B) when entering `markJobAsBeingNotified()`. The latter transaction B is rolled back, but then no log output occurs for transaction A.

The `NullPointerException` is thrown when the `TransactionalInterceptorRequiresNew` tries to get the status of the transaction:

```
if(getTransactionManager().getTransaction().getStatus() == Status.STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK) {
   getTransactionManager().rollback();
} else {
   getTransactionManager().commit();
}
```

Does anyone know why the transaction is suddenly `null`. Does the transaction manager returns transaction B, which has been finished?

EDIT:
When I try to, e.g., update an entity after the `forEach()` inside `checkForLongRunningJobs()`, an exception is thrown that says that a transaction is required. So after the process returns from `markJobAsBeingNotified()`, the transaction created for `checkForLongRunningJobs()` is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it: It's the `OptimisticLockException` that messes thinks up.

Here is a code snippet for `TransactionalInterceptorRequiresNew`:

```
try {
    proceed = proceed(ctx);
} finally {
    try {
        TransactionManager tm = getTransactionManager();
        if (tm instanceof TransactionManagerHelper) {
           ((TransactionManagerHelper)tm).postInvokeTx(false,true);
        }
        // Exception handling for proceed method call above can set TM/TRX as setRollbackOnly
        if(getTransactionManager().getTransaction().getStatus() == Status.STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK) {
            getTransactionManager().rollback();
        } else {
            getTransactionManager().commit(); // <---- OptimisticLockException is thrown
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        String messageString =
                "Managed bean with Transactional annotation and TxType of REQUIRES_NEW " +
                        "encountered exception during commit " +
                        exception;
        _logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.FINE, CDI_JTA_MBREQNEWCT, exception);
        throw new TransactionalException(messageString, exception);  <---- new Exception is thrown
    }
    if (suspendedTransaction != null) {
        try {
            getTransactionManager().resume(suspendedTransaction); <---- suspended transaction is not resumed
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            String messageString =
                    "Managed bean with Transactional annotation and TxType of REQUIRED " +
                            "encountered exception during resume " +
                            exception;
            _logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.FINE, CDI_JTA_MBREQNEWRT, exception);
            throw new TransactionalException(messageString, exception);
        }
    }
```

It is thrown when `getTransactionManager().commit()` is called. This exception is catched and a new `TransactionalException` is thrown. But the suspended transaction is not resumed, so when control returns to `checkForLongRunningJobs()` the transaction in this context was not resumed and a `NullPointerException` is thrown when the method returns and the interceptor tries to get the status of the transaction.

Is this an intended behaviour? How is the exception handling supposed to be done in case of an `OptimisticLockException`?